# ¿Como debería formular la consulta para mostrar datos de una id?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando varias consulta a mi base de datos de tablas diferentes en la misma base de datos, al querer ver la información mas completa de una **ID** activo un .js que abre un cuadro abajo de mi lista y muestra una información mas completa de la **ID** seleccionada, mi problema esta en una consulta que es en la parte donde dice **Math Hash** en mi tabla arriba donde solo se ve **Hash** si muestra el dato bien ya que el primero se hizo un baneo cuando el **Hash** tenia un codigo designado pero el segundo se dio el baneo cuando el **Hash** aun no estaba designado, al querer ver mas informacion de esa **ID** en las 2 consultas me sale el mismo código cuando no debería
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es la información del primer **ID** se podría decir que esta bien pero al querer ver la información de la segunda **ID**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este me muestra el mismo codigo de **Hash** cuando no debería ya que no tiene uno designado, estoy realizando la misma consulta pero no me esta funcionando de igual forma

```
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
require_once('steam.php');

$ext_query = "";

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $ext_query = " where bid=".$_GET['id'];
}

$dbTable = "amx_bans";
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

$dbTable2 = "pug_serverstats";
$query2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable2) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

$dbTable3 = "pug_playerstats";
$query3 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable2) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

if(!isset($_GET['pug_index']))
{
    $pug_index = 1;
}
else
{
    $pug_index = $_GET['pug_index'];
}

$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable .$ext_query ) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));

$query2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable2.' WHERE ('.$dbTable2.'.pug_index = '.$pug_index.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db));
$pug_info = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);

$query3 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable3.' WHERE ('.$dbTable3.'.pug_index = '.$pug_index.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db));
$pug_info2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
?>

<?php while ($betados = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <div class="betado_stats_info">
        <div class="user_info">
            <div class="info_prim">
                <div class="user_foto">
                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                </div>
                <div class="info_p">
                    <p class="p1">
                        Apodo :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo substr($betados['player_nick'], 0, 15);
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Status :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo $betados["player_id"];
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Perfil de Steam :
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($betados["player_id"]);?>/">
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                ?>
                                https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($betados["player_id"]);
                            } ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Razón :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo $betados["ban_reason"];
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Administrador :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo $betados["admin_nick"];
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Fecha del Ban :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($betados["ban_created"]-14400));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($betados["ban_created"]-14400));
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Fecha de Expiración :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                $diasBaneados = floor($betados["ban_length"] / 1440);
                                $horasBaneadas = floor($betados["ban_length"] / 60);
                                ?>
                                <?php if($betados["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php }
                                else if($betados["expired"] == 1)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Expirado
                                <?php }
                                else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                                <?php } 
                                else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                                <?php }
                                else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo $betados["ban_length"] ?> minutos;
                                <?php } 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                Nunca
                            <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Pov Demo :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($pug_info["pug_index"])
                            {
                                echo $pug_info["pug_hltv"];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                Sin demo
                            <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Math Hash :
                        <a>
                            <?php if($pug_info2["pug_index"])
                            {
                                ?>
                                <a onclick=""><?php echo $pug_info["pug_hash"]; ?></a>
                            <?php }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                <span style=color:#999999;>No estaba en partida</span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }
```